Depends: wine-stable-i386:i386 (= 9.0.0.0~focal-1)
Hi im new to lunix and i have a Ubuntu 22.04 i'm currently facing issues with installing wine which when ever i try to install it using cmd i get that error code sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine-stable:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not installable
Depends: wine-stable-i386:i386 (= 9.0.0.0~focal-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
i follow all the steps that are mentioned on winehq website but nothing changed
